# How Do You Locate a Hidden Network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

How do I disable or block a Hidden Network?  It is visible all the time with a high signal strength  always be checked off as "connect automatically" even with repeated attempts to uncheck it.  Previous related topic posts suggest this is from an upgrade in one's router, but when I turn power off to my router (unplug connection) the Hidden Network is still present with a strong signal.  Given how many people are experiencing this, I doubt that it is simply "one of the neighbours" choosing to hide their SSID.  I live in a rural area surrounded by elderly folks who aren't tech saavy and all the other neighbour signals can be accounted for and are not full strength such as this one.  Is it is a 5G add-on for expanded services?.

**How do we locate its source so we can eliminate it?**  Either via whoever it belongs to, or getting a different router (if that is the source) or some other means - once we know the source.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find a router at an unknown location in a house?](https://superuser.com/questions/1063636/how-to-find-a-router-at-an-unknown-location-in-a-house)

Comment: Can you see MAC addresses (aka BSSIDs) of the hidden network and your real network? Is there a Huawei LTE modem anywhere nearby?